# How to Implement a method inside Activity class

Tags: java, android

I'm just starting to learn Android programming with Android Studio and unfortunately, but I have a big problem with probably a very simple thing, namely in the layout file of the main activity, I assigned the startActivity() method to the `android:onClick` property of the both buttons (android:onClick="startActivity()").

And now I should in the MainActivity class, implement startActivity() method but.... I do not know how to do it.
I saw that I should have in MainActivity: `public void startActivity(View v)`. I tried and I was looking for solutions for a few hours and I already lost hope.
Especially that I can implement e.g. View.OnClickListener but methods, startActivity() can not do anymore. How could I implement this method?

I assigned the startActivity() method to the android:onClick property of the both buttons in activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="startActivity()"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="startActivity()"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />
```

Next i should in the MainActivity class, implement startActivity() method but.... I do not know how to do it :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements startActivity() {



    Button  b1, b2;
    EditText et1, et2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        public void startActivity(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
                String name = et1.getText().toString();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", name);
                i.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://www.google.pl/"));
                startActivity(i);     }

    }

}
```

Comment: please add your code show that we can help you

Comment: One thing is Android. Another one is Android Studio. Welcome. http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be great if you provide more background - are your following a tutorial and when yes, which one. Or sometimes a screenshot helps to understand where you stuck.

Comment: You don't need to write parenthesis () in pnClick attribute in XML file. Only put startActivity as the value like android:onClick="startActivity". startActivity method should be inside the class body , not inside the onCreate method.

Comment: Prashant Paliwal 
thank you very much! That was the solution to the problem I had to put the method inside the class! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrectly using `onClick` attribute. This is wrong:

```
android:onClick="startActivity()"
```

it should be:

```
android:onClick="startActivity"
```

Read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents

---

**Suggestion**
You should avoid using `android:onClick` in your xml. Use the `onClickListener` instead. It's important to separate your logic and UI layout so you don't need to think too much whenever your xml layout is changed. Use something like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something here when button is clicked.
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed everything according to your recommendations but now the message appears:error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<ResultActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context). The error is on this line: Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

Comment: ok, I found a solution, I had to place MainActivity.this instead of this. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Lukasso: Great!!! Please consider to mark an answer as an accepted answer. Or you can create your own answer if none of the answers is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [ישו אוהב אותך9A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758255/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9A)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents

[**`Responding to Click Events`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents)

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"

    //onClick function/method name don't use round brackets

    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

and in your activity

```
//JAVA

/** Called when the user touches the button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}

//Kotlin

/** Called when the user touches the button */
fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}
```

and remove the  `tools:ignore="OnClick"`

i hope it helps

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change this

```
android:onClick="startActivity()"
```

to this:

```
android:onClick="startActivity"
```

Then move your startActivity method below OnCreate method. It is currently inside OnCreate